# Server not getting online while using nohup in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins freestyle job where I need to make my API server and Application server running. So i tried giving the below script

```
cd api-repo
npm run build
nohup npm run start &
cd ..
cd app-repo
nohup npm run start &
```

When i build, I am getting 502 Bad gateway error.

I tried executing it manually, and the servers were up. Also I build just one server using jenkins, its working fine.

My problem is when I try for two, its not working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will strongly suggest you to use `pm2` instead of running the application using a manual command. What `pm2` does is, it will keep the service running in case of any failures.

Try giving the absolute path to the `js` file to start the node server.

For example:

`nohup npm start /path/to/api-repo/yourjsfile.js &`

Please use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).